# How to add button to SimpleExpendableListAdapter

Tags: android

I already have completely working ExpendableListView, but i want to add buttons to group/child items, because my ExpendableListView is working with the DB and i want to add CRUD to each item. I use SimpleExpendableListAdapter.

I override this methods in my custom MySimpleExpandableListAdapter. I know, that i need to somehow override getGroupView and getChildView methods, but how i can override them to add a button with onClickListener?

```
public MySimpleExpandableListAdapter(Context context, List<? extends Map<String, ?>> groupData, int groupLayout, String[] groupFrom, int[] groupTo, List<? extends List<? extends Map<String, ?>>> childData, int childLayout, String[] childFrom, int[] childTo) {
    super(context, groupData, groupLayout, groupFrom, groupTo, childData, childLayout, childFrom, childTo);
}

@Override
public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    return super.getGroupView(groupPosition, isExpanded, convertView, parent);
}
```

This is my xml fragment_layout file with my expendable list

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" tools:context="stickeyd.teacherhelper.MainActivityPupilFragment">

<!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->


<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end" android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />

<ExpandableListView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/expandableListView"
    android:layout_gravity="center" />
```

And this is my main fragment with RelativeLayout

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main"
tools:context=".MainActivityFragment">

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/sliding_tabs"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:tabMode="scrollable"
    android:background="#dddddd" />
```

Initialization of my adapter

```
    DatabaseHelper mDatabaseHelper = DatabaseHelper.getInstance(context);
    SQLiteDatabase mDatabase = mDatabaseHelper.getReadableDatabase();

    Cursor cursor = mDatabase.query(DatabaseHelper.TABLE_CLASS, new String[]{
                    DatabaseHelper._ID, DatabaseHelper.CLASS_TITLE, DatabaseHelper.CLASS_TEACHER, DatabaseHelper.CLASS_DESCRIPTION}, null,
            null,
            null,
            null,
            null
    );

    Map<String, String> map;
    ArrayList<Map<String, String>> groupDataList = new ArrayList<>();

    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
        map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put("groupName",cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.CLASS_TITLE)));
        groupDataList.add(map);
    }

    cursor.close();

    String groupFrom[] = new String[] { "groupName" };

    int groupTo[] = new int[] { android.R.id.text1 };

    ArrayList<ArrayList<Map<String, String>>> сhildDataList = new ArrayList<>();

    for (Map object: groupDataList) {

        String group = object.get("groupName").toString();
        String query = "SELECT * FROM " + DatabaseHelper.TABLE_PUPIL + " WHERE " +
                DatabaseHelper.PUPIL_CLASS + " = '" + group + "'"   ;

        cursor = mDatabase.rawQuery(query,null);

        ArrayList<Map<String, String>> сhildDataItemList = new ArrayList<>();

        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
            String firstName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.PUPIL_FIRSTNAME));
            map = new HashMap<>();
            map.put("firstName", firstName);
            сhildDataItemList.add(map);
        }
        cursor.close();
        сhildDataList.add(сhildDataItemList);
    }

    String childFrom[] = new String[] { "firstName" };
    int childTo[] = new int[] { android.R.id.text1 };

    return new MySimpleExpandableListAdapter(
            context, groupDataList,
            android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1, groupFrom,
            groupTo, сhildDataList, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
            childFrom, childTo);

}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(SimpleExpandableListAdapter adapter) {
    super.onPostExecute(adapter);
    MyBus.getInstance().post(new ExpListAsyncTaskEvent(adapter));

}
```

I need to add button to each group item of my ExpendableList, maybe i can somehow add custom layout with my button to group view? That would be the best solution for me

Thank you

Comment: I can tell you how to programatically add a button to the view you return in getGroupView() is that what you need?

Comment: Nanoc, yes, exactly. Thank you

Comment: So the layout you are inflating is "simple_expandable_list_item_1.xml"? then my answer code should be working why is it finding a LinearLayout instead of the TextView?

Comment: Don't know why... Seems, i need to use BaseExpandableListAdapter instead of this simple version. With Simple version there are too many problems.

Comment: If need anything more than the standard layout, yes you should use a BaseAdapter.

Answer (score 0):

To add a button to the groupView you can do this:

```
@Override
public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    TextView v = (TextView)super.getGroupView(groupPosition, isExpanded, convertView, parent);
    LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(v.getContext());
    ll.addView(v);
    ll.addView(new Button(v.getContext()));
    return ll;
}
```

That should add an empty button at 0,0 to your View (While your row content is a simple TextView).

Hope this helps.

Comment: I have this exception with your solution

`java.lang.ClassCastException: android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView cannot be cast to android.view.ViewGroup`

Comment: Thats because i cant see your xml layout, if its root is a textView then you need to add a layout, i update my answer.

Comment: Now i have this exception `java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.LinearLayout cannot be cast to android.widget.TextView`

But this is my mistake, i will update my question to show you my layout files and Initialization of my ExpendableListView. Thank you for your time.

Comment: Are your rows using different xmls? because LinearLayout will cast to ViewGroup but TextView will not. You will need to perform a check if thats the case.

Comment: I updated my post, you can see my layouts there. Hope that helps you to find an answer. I don't use other layouts for child items or groups, that's all that i have. I just init my adapter with data and set it to my ExpendableListView. That's all.